# TableRow TextView moves down on longer Text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

I tried to make a timetable app for my school for fun by using a TableLayout with TableRow with TextView in it. The problem is that when i enter a longer text the TextView moves down.
Here is my xml: 
    `

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Mo"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tu"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="WeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWe"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>`
```

[and here is a picture of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxCWJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Upd for your layout type.
This seems works fine. Change your textColor and other parameters as you like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Mo"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Tu"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="WeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWeWe"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I use a relative layout with a tablelayout in it and in the tablelayout there are is the table row and in there are the textviews

Comment: the problem is i want to have a fixed hight of the table row

Comment: it still does the same thing but now you dont see it because the text view background is the same as the rest. But i need the background of the tablerow to be different for the grids

Comment: ok it aligns the text baseline to the baseline of the other textviews. can i turn that off. As soon as i set the first or second textView gravity to center it moves down again

Comment: I upd, try again

Comment: I fixed it by setting the layout_gravity to fill_vertical. thx for your time.